# Protocol UITableViewDataSource is not called from xib - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib, nib

I don't know why my protocol `UITableViewDataSource` is not execute when i run the APP.

Here my xib design:
[image]

My init of class from xib is: `CustomSearchDestination`

```
 @IBOutlet weak var searchText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let xibName = "CustomSearchDestination"
var destinationListLocal: [Destinos] = []
var SearchViewControllerView: SearchViewController?

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    xibSetup(xibName)

    SearchViewControllerView = SearchViewController()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    searchText.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
    xibSetup(xibName)
}
```

Inside of this class have implemented the protocol `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

```
extension CustomSearchDestination: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("El count es: \(destinationListLocal.count)")
    return destinationListLocal.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    searchText.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text
}}

extension CustomSearchDestination: UITableViewDataSource {

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let index = indexPath.row as Int

    if destinationListLocal.count == 0 {
        if let str = destinationListLocal[index].desDestino {
            cell.textLabel?.text = str
        }
    }

    return cell
}}
```

Can someone point me my mistake?

EDIT: My hierarchy is:

I have a xib where i put other xib like this:
[image]

this is my class `CustomViewHandler`. So.. my class `CustomSearchDestination` is a class of the superClass CustomViewHandler. 
At the same time is a class of `CustomSearch`

```
class CustomViewHandler : UIView {
var view: UIView!

var controllerView : UIView!

// Keyboard
var activeField : UITextField?
var isKeyboardVisible = false
var fixValue : CGFloat?
var keyboardSize : CGFloat = 280


fileprivate func loadViewFromNib(_ nibName: String) -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)

    // Assumes UIView is top level and only object in CustomView.xib file
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}

func xibSetup(_ nibName: String) {
    view = loadViewFromNib(nibName)

    // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
    view.frame = bounds

    // Makes the view stretch with containing view
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)

}}
```

Comment: Have you declared `CustomSearchDestination` as the `UITableView` class in storyboard? i.e. "Show the Identity inspector" tab when selecting `UITableView` in storyboard, modify the `Class` field to point to `CustomSearchDestination` class.

Comment: my CustomSearchDestination is a UIView can't cast to UITableView to link the tableView...i guess

Comment: Oh okay I see the hierarchy now.. You still should be able to apply the `CustomSearchDestination` class to that `UIView` then, right?

Comment: yes...! i update the post with more details.

Comment: So then there is also a class called `CustomSearch`? I am interested if you try to apply the `CustomSearchDestination` class to the `UIView` which is parent view of your `UITableView`. Perhaps you can show Identity inspector for that `UIView` which is above the `UITableView`?

Comment: add more details...is the correct way this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149849/discussion-between-michael-fourre-and-xhinoda).

Comment: please help..! :(